# Issue with JPA statement "translation"

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a JPA statement which is like this

```
select p from Proposal p where p.creationTime > :startDate AND p.creationTime < :stopDate AND ((p.owner = :owner) OR (:member MEMBER OF p.sharedWithTeam.members)) ORDER BY p.creationTime DESC
```

But it never generates any result. I use EclipseLink.

After digging a bit into the generated SQL, I found out that it translates the query into something that can never be true!

```
SELECT XXX FROM userteam_users t3, USERTEAM t2, USERS t1, PROPOSAL t0 WHERE ((((t0.CREATIONTIME > ?) AND (t0.CREATIONTIME < ?)) AND ((t0.OWNER_username = ?) OR (? = t1.username))) AND ((t2.ID = t0.SHAREDWITHTEAM_ID) AND ((t3.teams_ID = t2.ID) AND (t1.username = t3.members_username)))) ORDER BY t0.CREATIONTIME DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

(I only included the from and where clause to make it shorter...)

I can't see what is wrong with my JPQL query. Could it be my use of "OR"? or my "bold" use of the member of condition?

EDIT: in fact, the statement can be true, I misread it. BUT I have proposals with NO shared user team, so the first condition is always false in this case, and it should be true (in my view)

Thanks!

Comment: well, I think the issue is with the member of so I turned it around and replaced "OR (:member MEMBER OF p.sharedWithTeam.members)" by "(p.sharedWithTeam IS NOT NULL AND p.sharedWithTeam IN :userTeams). That worked indeed.

Comment: you can answer your own question. So, the people will know how did you find the answer without need to read the comments section